# Android image capturing and scaling

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, jpeg, android-camera

I am using the **Camera activity** to capture the JPEG image. After image is saved and the controll is returned back to my application activity I would like to to determine the captured JPEG image dimensions without loading the whole image into memory via **Bitmap** object - can it be easily done somehow?

Is there any class, which reads the JPEG header and give me such information? I would like to avoid OOM conditions - but might be it is not a problem to load the whole image into memory - is it?

After knowing the dimensions I would like to use **BitmapFactory** to scale the image.

Thanks a lot

Kind Regards,

STeN

Comment: As a first approach I use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java. But I welcome any comments over this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [work-around](http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/androidCamera101.pdf) (see 2nd approach) by setting the quality?

> bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75,
>   pfos);

You would have to do a trial run to see what size the quality gets you though...

*The first approach creates a log file to get the width and height but not sure if you wanted the extra step of looking at a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class to read the image width and height.