# how to get the size of an image in java

Tags: java, image, url

hi
  I am using Jtidy parser in java.

---

```
URL url = new URL("http://l1.yimg.com/t/frontpage/baba-ramdev-310511-60.jpg");  
Image image = new ImageIcon(url).getImage();
int imgWidth = image.getWidth(null);
int imgHeight = image.getHeight(null);
```

---

Above code is working fine,I am getting height & width properly.But I want to see the size of an image (for example whether it is in KB,or in MB ).Please help me,how to get the size of an image.Is there any method.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with JTidy - I changed the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image height and width using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java)

Answer (score 12):

This is one of the simplest method to find the dimensions of image.

```
 URL url=new URL("Any web image url");
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
 int height = image.getHeight();
 int width = image.getWidth();
 System.out.println("Height : "+ height);
 System.out.println("Width : "+ width);
```

Comment: Any change of getting wether this is a jpg, png, or else? I can probably parse t from url, but maybe it should be a better way?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
url.openConnection().getContentLength();
```

If this doesn't work, you can load the stream using:

```
url.openStream()
```

...and read the stream until the end, counting how many bytes were actually read. You might also use [`CountingInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) decorator to reuse the stream later. However the first code snippet seems to work.

Comment: @Ishtar: I think he does not mean to call `available()`, but read all the bytes until end-of-stream, and count them. It could be worded better, though.

Comment: @Ishtar: Yep, *Paŭlo Ebermann* is right, I meant reading the stream byte-by-byte, maybe in more sane manner. Look at my edit, I tried to clarify my idea.

Comment: @Paŭlo You know that, because you know that you should not do that ;), but I've seen confusing about it. So: @Tomasz - Thanks for the clarification! I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 6):

How to count your bytes & eat them too.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

class ImageInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://l1.yimg.com/t/frontpage/baba-ramdev-310511-60.jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[2^16];
        int read = is.read(b);
        while (read>-1) {
            baos.write(b,0,read);
            read = is.read(b);
        }
        int countInBytes = baos.toByteArray().length;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            baos.toByteArray());
        Image image = ImageIO.read(bais);
        int width = image.getWidth(null);
        int height = image.getHeight(null);
        String imageInfo =
            width + "x" + height + " px, " +
            countInBytes + " bytes.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            new JLabel(imageInfo, new ImageIcon(image), SwingConstants.CENTER));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a HEAD request  to get the content length

```
URL url = new URL("http://l1.yimg.com/t/frontpage/baba-ramdev-310511-60.jpg");
//Set the user agent
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
//Use Http to get the head request
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//head request to minimal response
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
length = (urlConnection).getContentLengthLong();
```