# How can I get height and width of an image?

Tags: java, image, asynchronous

Why is the following bit of code returns Height: -1 which means that the height is yet not known. How to get height of the image?

```
 try {
        // Create a URL for the image's location
        URL url = new URL("http://bmw-2006.auto-one.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/bmw-m3-2006-3.jpg");

        // Get the image
        java.awt.Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);

        System.out.println("Height: " + image.getHeight(null));


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java - depending on whether use of the AWT Image class is required.

Comment: @berry120 - I was going to say something about Java not wanting to look at the image too long being the problem ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.net.URL-) or [`ImageIO.read(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) instead.  It will block while loading, and the image width & height will be known after it returns.

#### E.G.

[image]

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

class SizeOfImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg");
        final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
        final String size = bi.getWidth() + "x" + bi.getHeight();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel l = new JLabel( 
                    size, 
                    new ImageIcon(bi), 
                    SwingConstants.RIGHT );
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Alternately, add a [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html) to the image being loaded asynchronously by the [`Toolkit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) and wait until it is completely loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this:

```
    try {
        // Create a URL for the image's location
        URL url = new URL("http://bmw-2006.auto-one.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/bmw-m3-2006-3.jpg");

        // Get the image
        Image image = ImageIO.read(url);

        System.out.println("Height: " + image.getHeight(null));


    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `java.awt.Toolkit` approach won't block, so will return -1 and notify the observer (or not in your case because it's null) when it is loaded. If you do want it asynchronously then you'll need to provide a callback in the form of an image observer.

Oh, and don't just ignore exceptions, at least print the stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

Because the image is loaded asynchronously, in the background.

As the `getHeight()` javadoc says, you need to provide an [ImageObserver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html) (instead of `null`), which is called when the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`Toolkit#createImage(...)` is **non-blocking**. Generally I would rather use `javax.imageio.ImageIO`to read images.

To wait for the `Toolkit#createImage(...)`, use:

```
MediaTracker mediaTracker = new MediaTracker(component);
mediaTracker.addImage(image);
try {
    mediaTracker.waitForAll();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After that, you can call `image.getHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

createImage runs in background to load the Image.

use a MediaTracker to wait for the loading and then use getHeight (and use a valid ImageObserver to prevent errors)