# Failure to Loop Through Map in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, iteration, aem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

I'm following this solution to no effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835742/666468

I am trying to output this Map:

```
//protected Map<String,String> getImageTagAttributes()
Image image = new Image(resource);
for (Map<String, String> foo : image.getImageTagAttributes()) {
        String key = foo.getKey();
        String value = foo.getValue();

        //output here
    }
```

But I get this error: **Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable**

I imported *java.util.Iterator* as well, but no luck.

p.s. I wish I could install and use JSTL, but it's not my call.

Comment: What is returned by `image.getImageTagAttributes()`? A `Map` has a key/value pair mechanism. You need to use an `EntrySet` to iterate over the `Map`.

Comment: Use the iterator as suggested in the following solution :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java

Comment: How did you miss the `entrySet()` method in the answer you found?

Comment: @BalusC, I presumed `countries.entrySet()` is unique to the example in question, and not to me specifically. My knowledge in Java is rookie at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where did you get that `Image` class, but if `image.getImageTagAttributes()` returns `Map<String, String>` then maybe try it this way

```
Image image = new Image(resource);
Map<String, String> map = image.getImageTagAttributes();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> foo : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = foo.getKey();
    String value = foo.getValue();

    //output here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate a Map in for each loop.

Get the map object keyset and then iterate it.

Then inside the for loop try retrieving the value for each key from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Because this not the correct way to iterate over a Map :

```
    Image image = new Image(resource);
    Map<String, String> foo =  image.getImageTagAttributes();
    Set<String> key = foo.keyset(); 
     for ( k : keys ) {
           String value = foo.get(k);
        //output here
    }
```

or you can interate that way :

```
    Image image = new Image(resource);
    Map<String, String> foo =  image.getImageTagAttributes();
    Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> entries = foo.entrySet();

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : entries){
       String key  = e.getKey();
       String value = e.getValue();
        //output
    }
```

In my answer, I suppose that `image.getImageTagAttributes();` returns a `Map<String,String>`