# Get Image Width and Height in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I just want to ask how to get the width and height of an image, because this returns -1 for width and height:

```
private void resizeImage(Image image){
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();

    int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
    System.out.println("Width:" + imageWidth);
    System.out.println("Height:" + imageHeight);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you get -1 because width and height is null

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like this :

```
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
int width          = bimg.getWidth();
int height         = bimg.getHeight();
```

as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083914/2673306) says

Comment: not worked when it comes to a large size. I just get 800X600. it seems that the `BufferedImage`'s param `WritableRaster` is `ByteInterleavedRaster`, which has the `maxX` and `maxY`.

Answer (score 3):

With [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/), you can get image width and height with better performance, without reading entire image to memory.

Sample code below is using Sanselan 0.97-incubator (Commons Imaging is still SNAPSHOT as I write this):

```
final ImageInfo imageInfo = Sanselan.getImageInfo(imageData);
int imgWidth = imageInfo.getWidth();
int imgHeight = imageInfo.getHeight();
```

Comment: **Avoid using Apache Commons Imaging!** It misses basic functionality. No support for .webp. There is a feature request for it from **2011 and it is still not implemented**: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMAGING-57

Answer (score 0):

Exactly why this happens in your case is unclear, you don't specify exactly what `image` actually is.

Anyway, the answer can be found in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getWidth%28java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29):

```
public abstract int getWidth(ImageObserver observer)
```

> Determines the width of the image. If the width is not yet known, this method returns -1 and the specified ImageObserver object is notified later.

The width and height obiously cannot be immediately determined for the image in question. You need to pass an `ImageObserver` instance which will have [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html#imageUpdate%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method called when height and width can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static BufferedImage resize(final Image image, final int width, final int height){
    assert image != null;
    final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, image instanceof BufferedImage ? ((BufferedImage)image).getType() : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    final Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

The code posted above is one way of resizing an image. Generally to get the width and height of an image, you may do:

```
image.getWidth(null);
image.getHeight(null);
```

This is all under the assumption that the image is not null.