# how to compare two images in java?in terms of height and width

Tags: java, image, comparison, height, width

i had been working on my project which encompasses the technique for comparing images. I  want to compare two images in java in terms of height and width, i can't compare it if any one can help it please do..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java Might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a head start. You can use something like this and that should get you going.

```
Image image;

public static void listFilesForFolder(File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

        Image image;

        try {


            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users//workspace//ImageProcessing//images//" + fileEntry.getName()));

            BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;

            int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
            int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
            yourImageClass.setHeight(imageHeight);
            yourImageClass.setWidth(imageWidth);
            arrayListOfImageClasses.add(yourImageClass);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());

    }
}
```

These are the jars you can use :

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Hope this gets you going.

Comment: actually i have to capture frames from a specified video and compare that frames with each other to find the portion wise difference between them .... will the above code be usefull. for that???

Comment: Yes, it will be. You need to get the frames and then compare the size of the frames.

Comment: how to compare them ?? how to pass the path of two images simultaneously???

Comment: It is easy. Write a function that reads the images. Then create a class Image with two attributes - height and width. When you read through the files you keep adding the Images to an ArrayList. Then do comparisons in whatever way you want. I have edited my code to give you some hints.

Comment: thanks for ur help buddy will check it tomorrow and concern you back.

Comment: hey its not working if u can help me out please ....

Comment: Which part is not working ?

Comment: it says method not found..... while executing setwidth and setheight method.

Comment: Did you import the packages I mentioned ?

Comment: yeys i did.... then also it didn't worked

Comment: What error did it throw ? And what Java version are you using ?

Comment: i am using jdk 1.8.    It states as "cannot find symbol " on line where we declared the setheight and setwidth method....  Also says "Illegal start of expression" at method declaration of "public static void listFilesForFolder(File folder) ".

Comment: i am trying naivesimilarity program from java cookbook bt couldn't get the dissimilar image .... can anyone help me on that.???