# Finding dimensions of a .gif file

Tags: java, image, gif

I'm looking for a way to find the pixel dimensions of a .gif file in Java.

Will I have to convert one of the images from the gif to a BufferedImage and get it from there or is there a simpler way?

Using ImageIO doesn't work because I need to use ImageIcons to draw a gif using Swing. Here's how I'm drawing it.

```
attackImage = new ImageIcon("assets/Attacks/EnergyAttack.gif").getImage();
g.drawImage(attackImage, getX() + 20, getY(), null);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image height and width using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java)

Comment: @MTCoster no because this specifically relates to gifs, not jpegs/pngs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) instance, you can simply use its [`getIconHeight()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getIconHeight()) and [`getIconWidth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getIconWidth()) methods to get these values:

```java
ImageIcon attackImage = new ImageIcon("assets/Attacks/EnergyAttack.gif");
int attackImageHeight = attackImage.getIconHeight();
int attackImageWidth = attackImage.getIconWidth();
g.drawImage(attackImage.getImage(), getX() + 20, getY(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I quote you:

> I need to use ImageIcons to draw a gif using Swing.

Have you tried using ImageIcon.[getIconHeight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getIconHeight--) and ImageIcon.[getIconWidth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getIconWidth--)? Additionally, if you have a fixed-size view, you might consider using ImageIcon.[getImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage--) followed by Image.[getScaledInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance-int-int-int-).