# How to create a map for (key - image name // value - image-file) in Scala

Tags: scala

```
  def getListOfImageNames(dir: String): List[String] = {
    val names = new File(dir)
    names.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
      .map(_.getName).toList
  }


  def getListOfImages(dir: String): List[String] = {
    val files = new File(dir)
    files.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
      .filter(_.getName.endsWith(".png"))
      .filter(_.getName.endsWith(".jpg"))
      .map(_.getPath).toList
  }
```

I have a directory where I have different photos, small size, large size and I have already managed to write methods which: one of them only pulls out the names of the photos and the other the photos. How can I now combine them into a map, for example, then calculate their resolution using the method, if the photo is larger than, for example, 500x500, add a prefix to the name and save it in the X folder. Do you have any ideas? I'm not experienced in Scala, but I like the language very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got you need to get map of image name to image path. You can achieve it like so:

```
def getImagesMap(dirPath: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val directory = new File(dirPath)
  directory.listFiles.collect{
    case file if file.isFile && 
         (file.getName.endsWith(".png") ||
         file.getName.endsWith(".jpg")) => 
      file.getName -> file.getPath
  }.toMap
}
```

here I use `collect` function. It's like combination of `map` and `filter` functions. Inside `collect` a pattern matching expression. If file matches pattern matching it will evaluate pair creation: file name to file path. Otherwise file just will be filtered. After I use `toMap` for conversion `Array[(String, String)]` to `Map[String, String]`. You can read more about `collect` [here](https://medium.com/@sergigp/using-scala-collect-3a9880f71e23).

Comment: Ok, it's looking nice, I will test it now

Comment: Works fine, could you show me how I can work with this Map? e.g. how i count all the pixels in every image? and output it?

Comment: @SzymonDejewski you can `filter` Map by width and length of image, using `BufferedImage` class and `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java